# Azure ARM Template : How to use Copy to generate both property name and property value

Tags: arrays, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have a parameter as below:

```
"parameters": {
    "input":{
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue":[
        {
          "name":"**globalName1**",
          "value": "**globalValue1**"
        },
        {
          "name": "globalName2",
          "value": "globalValue2"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Is it possible to create a variable globalParametersVar using Copy on Input so its value would be as below:

```
    "globalParametersVar": {
        "**globalName1**": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "**globalValue1**"
                },
        "globalName2": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "globalValue2"
                }  
    },
```

In our existing code, there're something similar as below. You could see the globalParameters section is hardcoded. I'm trying to create globalParameters for AzureDataFactory dynamically based on the name/value from the input array

```
    "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('factoryNameTest')]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
      "properties": {
        "**globalParameters**": {
          "globalName1": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "globalValue1"
          },
          "globalName2": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "globalValue2"
          },
          "globalName3": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "globalValue3"
          }
        }
      },
      "location": "west us2",
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      }
    }   
    ],
```

I tried to use Copy but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by leveraging [reduce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-lambda#reduce) and [lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-lambda).

I've written this using bicep because it makes the ARM authoring experience a lot faster, whilst still compiling down the ARM you want. (plus the fact that writing in ARM json is so 2020 )

Here's the output

```json
"debugGlobObj": {
        "type": "Object",
        "value": {
          "globalName1": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "globalValue1"
          },
          "globalName2": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "globalValue2"
          }
        }
      }
```

### bicep

```
param input array = [{name: 'globalName1', value: 'globalValue1'}, {name: 'globalName2', value: 'globalValue2'}]

var globalVar = [for i in input: {
  '${i.name}' : {
    type: 'string'
    value: i.value
  }
}]

output debugGlobArray array = globalVar
output debugGlobObj object = reduce(globalVar, {}, (cur, next) => union(cur, next))
```

### ARM

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "input": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
        {
          "name": "globalName1",
          "value": "globalValue1"
        },
        {
          "name": "globalName2",
          "value": "globalValue2"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "copy": [
      {
        "name": "globalVar",
        "count": "[length(parameters('input'))]",
        "input": {
          "[format('{0}', parameters('input')[copyIndex('globalVar')].name)]": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[parameters('input')[copyIndex('globalVar')].value]"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "resources": [],
  "outputs": {
    "debugGlobArray": {
      "type": "array",
      "value": "[variables('globalVar')]"
    },
    "debugGlobObj": {
      "type": "object",
      "value": "[reduce(variables('globalVar'), createObject(), lambda('cur', 'next', union(lambdaVariables('cur'), lambdaVariables('next'))))]"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this help solve my problem in such an elegant way.